# How to recognize and print the segmented character

Tags: matlab

I'm applying some image processing techniques in MATLAB I was able to segment the license plate as show in the figure below:

[image]

Now if I apply the followig code in a for loop:

```
ocrResults = ocr(finalImage);
ocrResults.Text
```

I'm getting output like `VV`, `u` etc that means these characters are not recognized properly. **So, how can I fix that?** It's not mandatory to use the OCR class so any other solution will also work.

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB's `ocr` function accepts additional inputs as Name/Value pairs. In your case, to limit the output to numeric values, simply add in the following parameters:

`ocrResults = ocr( finalImage, 'CharacterSet', '0123456789' );`

However, I'm not certain doing just this will get you the output you desire. It might be helpful to erode the image and add additional blackspace around each character. Take advantage of other possible input parameters which may be added, such as `'TextLayout'`.

Comment: Yes this didn't help. Is there any other way other than using the OCR.